# Keeping a running total with Javascript in a span element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a piece of code that is supposed to keep a running total. More specifically what I would like it to do is, every time you click the button to add the sub total to the total, it should keep adding into the subtotal. The way the whole thing works now is, there is three meal items to choose from in a dropdown that each have their own price. When a food item is selected, the user types in how many of that item they want. Then user clicks the add to total button to add the food item to one text field. Under that field is a span that shows the grand total after a $3.50 delivery charge is added on. The span is where I want the running total to keep adding the sum every time the button is clicked. I am new to Javascript so I've been trying my best. I've also looked at topics here on SO to see if I can find something similar to my issue and I've seen some that are close but not quite what I'm looking for. Here"s my code...

```
 <script>



    function myTotal() 
{
  var meals = document.getElementById("foodItems").value;

  var howMany = document.getElementById("itemTotal").value;

  var shippingCost = "3.50";

  var totalBill = parseFloat(meals) * howMany + parseFloat(shippingCost);

  var addingTotal = parseFloat(meals) * howMany;

  var runTotal = document.getElementById("runningTotal").value;

   if (isNaN(totalBill)) { // Cash calculator
        document.getElementById("total").value = "Invalid amount"
        //alert("result of isNaN" );   //The input amount is a non numeric string. It is or contains letters and/or spaces
  } 
    else { //adds total to the sub total field
        document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + parseFloat(addingTotal).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        //Convert input value into a floating point number.  toFixed() requires a number value to work with
  }//end Cash Calculator

  var i = ""; //This piece is where I'm trying to begin the running total

  if(i=totalBill, i=howMany*totalBill, i++ ){//adds delivery charge + subtotal. But doesn't keep a running total
    document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML = parseFloat(totalBill).toFixed(2);
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML = parseFloat(i++) * howMany;
    }
}

</script>

<form id="survey" name="survey" method="get" action="formHandler.php" class="col-4">

<!-- enter your forms code below -->

<div id="fieldset">
<legend>Place an Order!</legend>

<h3>There is a $3.50 delivery fee</h3>
<fieldset>
    <label for="foodItems">Quick Meal Food Items</label>
        <select name="foodItems" id="foodItems">
            <option value="6.00">Pepperoni Pizza - $6.00</option>
            <option value="3.00">Bacon BBQ Burger - $3.00</option>
            <option value="8.00">Steak and Eggs - $8.00</option>
</fieldset>

    <!--The "input" element has "required" in the parameters so the user must fill out all fields but the email.-->

<fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="itemTotal" id="itemTotal" size="25" required>How Many Orders?(Limit To 5 per Meal Type)</input>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="button" name="click" id="button" value="Add to Order" onClick="myTotal()">

    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="25">Grand Total</input>
<br>
    <span id="runningTotal"></span> <!--runningTotal span-->
</fieldset>

    <label for="name">Name: (First, Last)</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="25" required></input>

    <label for="Address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address" id="address"  size="25" required></input>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="40" maxlength="40"></input>
<br><br>

    <label for="checkbox">Sign me up for deals via email</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="Signup" checked="checked"></input>



<input type="submit" method="post" value="Submit" class="button"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome! Please address any confusion please. I want to be as clear as possible to try to get the best help for me and others here on SO. I also hope my question isn't off topic. Like I said, I tried to find something pertaining to this here on SO. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have the total of your line item. You have your running total. You're just overwriting the running total instead of adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? [(jsfiddle here)](https://jsfiddle.net/ds3ex3yp/2/)

```
function myTotal() 
{
    // Error checking removed....

  // Calculate cost of current item
  var itemSelect = document.getElementById("foodItems");
  var mealCost = parseFloat(itemSelect.value);
  var howMany = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemTotal").value);
  var thisItemCost = mealCost * howMany;

  var shippingCost = 3.5;

  // Get running total from the "total" text box
  var runTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);
  // Only add shipping cost once
  if (isNaN(runTotal) || 0 == runTotal) runTotal = shippingCost;
  // Add this item to total and update "total" text box
  document.getElementById("total").value = (thisItemCost + runTotal).toFixed(2);

  // Add item to span
  document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML += "</br>" + 
            itemSelect.options[itemSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML +
        " x " + howMany + 
        " .... $" + thisItemCost.toFixed(2);
 }
```

Comment: @RobinJennings [You're Welcome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)